# EF Code First: how to fix relationships using the fluent api

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I've got a simple data model described with Enitity Framework but still can't fix a problem with the relationships in my model.
I've tried some approaches using the Fluent API but always got non descriptive exceptions.

Here's a code:

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
}

public class Language : Entity
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public String Verbal { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PostContent> Contents { get; set; }
}

public class Post : Entity
{
    public virtual ICollection<PostContent> Contents { get; set; }
}

public class PostContent
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public Int32 PostId { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public Int32 LanguageId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PostId")]
    public virtual Post Post { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("LanguageId")]
    public virtual Language Language { get; set; }

    public String Content { get; set; }
}

public class BlogContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Language> Languages { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PostContent> PostContents { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}

public class BlogContextInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<BlogContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(BlogContext context)
    {
        //For test
        context.Languages.Add(new Language { Verbal = "Italian" });
        context.Languages.Add(new Language { Verbal = "English" });
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<BlogContext>(new BlogContextInitializer());

        using (BlogContext blogContext = new BlogContext())
        {
            //init on call.
            var langs = blogContext.Set<Language>().AsEnumerable();
            foreach (var lang in langs)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Language Id: {0}, Verbal: {1}", lang.Id, lang.Verbal);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I got:

> "The number of properties in the Dependent and Principal Roles in a
>   relationship constraint must be identical."

So I'm looking for a solution of this problem.

Comment: Where is the problem? What is the problem? What are you expecting? What is the result?

Comment: I got "The number of properties in the Dependent and Principal Roles in a relationship constraint must be identical." So I'm looking for a solution of this problem.

Comment: Maybe it is becuase language has 2 keys but postcontent defines only one for the FK

Comment: You inherit Language and Post from Entity. But in EF it means TPC or TPH structure for it. What is your case?

Comment: There's a problem that SQL doesn't support FK for a part of a primary key. So I just removed [Key] attribute from the verbal field.